# Vigenere Cipher Methods

Tags: encryption, classical-cipher, vigenere

Is there already a cipher which uses a method like vigenere yet the shifted encrypting alphabets are mixed?

i.e.

ASDFGHJKLZXCVBNMQWERTYUIOP
BNMQWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCV
CVBNMQWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZX

etc.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you mean. If you're suggesting permuting the rows of the Vigenére square to something other than alphabetical order, then your code can be deciphered in exactly the same way as an ordinary Vigenére cipher. You just need to use a different key, that's all.

Comment: Are you looking for info about the generic class of polyalphabetic ciphers? Vigenère is just a special degenerate case that uses fixed rotating alphabets; but polyalphabetic ciphers can use any set of alphabets.

Answer (score 1):

The [Jefferson Disk Cipher](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jefferson_disk) is an implementation of this. Each disk is a pre-scrambled alphabet, and the key is the wheel order.

Comment: The Disk Cipher is not operated by a keyword, rather the positioning of its wheels.